# Why is $q undefined in the following angularjs example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

At the line `var deferred = $q.defer();`

When I try to submit a simple form using the following code, I get: `TypeError: Unable to get property 'defer' of undefined or null reference`.

```
angular.module('app').controller('enrollCtl', function enrollCtl($q, $http)
{

    // Using 'Controller As' syntax, so we assign this to the vm variable (for viewmodel).
    var vm = this;
    // Bindable properties and functions are placed on vm.

    vm.applicantData = {
        FirstName: "",
        Comment: ""
    };

    vm.registerApplicant = function submitForm($q, $http)
    {

        console.log('posting data::' + vm.applicantData.FirstName)
        var serverBaseUrl = "https://test.com/TestForm";
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: serverBaseUrl,
            data: vm.applicantData
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg)
        {
            console.log(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (err, status)
        {
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;

    };

})
```

Comment: Remove $q from the parameters of the submitForm function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `$q` and `$http` twice as parameters, once at your controller and once at your function. The modules will only get injected in your controller, and the parameters of your function (where they have the value `undefined` if you call the function with nothing) shadow them.

Notice that you [should not use `$q.deferred` here anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), just return the promise that `$http` already gives you:

```
vm.registerApplicant = function submitForm() {
    console.log('posting data::' + vm.applicantData.FirstName)
    return $http({
//  ^^^^^^
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://test.com/TestForm",
        data: vm.applicantData
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (err, status) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```